# Laravel Eloquent / Many to Many Relations gives error ( Array to string conversion )

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to display all job posts that user have applied

Here is my Tables ..

```
applies   ->  | users_id | posts_id |
posts     ->  | id       | (other posts cols ... )
user_info ->  | id       | (name col etc...)
```

Ive tried `belongsToMany()` but gives error

> mb_strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given

Post model Relation

```
public function applies()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Applies::class ,'applies', 'users_id' , 'posts_id');
}
```

Applies model

```
   protected $table = 'applies';
    protected $primaryKey = ['user_id', 'id'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'posts_id'
    ];
```

Lastly Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $infos = Info::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first();
    $apply = Post::find(2)->applies ;
    var_dump($apply);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass pivot table name as  second parameter to `belongsToMany`

```
 return $this->belongsToMany(User::class ,'applies', 'users_id' , 'posts_id');
```

If you see the implementation method .second parameter as table name

```
  public function belongsToMany($related, $table = null, $foreignPivotKey = null, $relatedPivotKey = null,
                                  $parentKey = null, $relatedKey = null, $relation = null)
```

Comment: Oh thanks .. I added table now but this time gives  `mb_strpos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given` error

Comment: User::class not Applies::class for first param